# Windows Server - Bridge ip address of different subnets

Tags: networking, router, proxy, ip, windows-server

My Windows Server 2008 R2 has two network cards which are connected to physically separated networks.

The Adapters have the following IP settings:
LAN1 IP: 192.168.**2**.1 (Netmask 255.255.255.0)
LAN2 IP: 192.168.**3**.1 (Netmask 255.255.255.0)

In the LAN1 network there's a PC1 which should have access to a PC2 in LAN2 with a static IP 192.168.3.5

I think that it should be possible if I add a second IP to the Server LAN1 interface, let's say 192.168.2.5.

Now if PC1 wants to access PC2, it calls IP 192.168.2.5. The data goes to the Windows Server which then forwards it to 192.168.3.5 (two-way).

Adding a second IP Adress to an interface is no problem. But is it possible to set up Windows Server to forward all traffic between the two PC1 and PC2?

If that's not possible, it would be sufficient to just forward all HTTP/HTTPS traffic, i.e. something like a tansparent proxy on the Windows Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect networks you need a router.

If you like to connect 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 use your Windows server because
a) it is already connected to both networks
b) it has the RRAS (Routing and Remote Access) which turns the server into a router when configured

Next, you need to set the IPs of the server as default gateways on the clients. That'd be 192.168.2.1 default gateway for computer in net 192.168.2.0/24 and respectively 192.168.3.1 is the default gateway for computers in the 192.168.3.0/24 network

Lastly, you cannot do what you like to do. to be in to different networks with two different networks cards and then assign IPs like this, it won't work.

not working
Nic1: 192.168.3.1, 192.168.2.2
Nic2: 192.168.2.1, 192.168.3.2

working 2008 with rras enabled
server 
Nic1: 192.168.2.1
Nic2: 192.168.3.1

pc1
Nic1: 192.168.2.5, default gw 192.168.2.1

pc2
Nic1: 192.168.3.5, default gw 192.168.3.1

Best